# COM OpenOffice initialisation error

Tags: php, openoffice.org

I am coding in php and i have got a problem with talking to OpenOffice via COM.  I have already had to abandon several attempts to do some server side openoffice tricks due to the fact that nothing seems to work.  I have resigned myself to doing it locally and have found something that most peopld seem to agree is  pretty strightforward - not for me though suprise suprise.  It boils down to this command not working.

```
$osm = new COM("com.sun.star.ServiceManager") or die ("Please be sure that OpenOffice.org is installed.\n");
```

Can you give me some pointers please.  I have downloaded latest OpenOffice and it works well when tiggered from Windows desktop but that is as far as it goes.  Can you tell me what needs to be in place to use the code above from php.  At the moment I get a long pause followed by an error saying the COM object can't be initialised or similar - this happens both locally and when run from my website.

Where/How can i see if com.sun.star.moon.etc is registered on my system and ready and waiting to be called?  Which permissions are required (what does this even mean and how do i change them to be as they need to be)?  I found a service in windows called COM+ which was not running and started that, but it didn't help.

Anyone - please help!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

1) Make sure that you are trying that code in Windows ONLY.

2) In order for you to be able to use the PHP COM class, you first need to enable it in your php.ini. So add this line extension=php_com_dotnet.dll and restart Apache or IIS.

3) Install OpenOffice on the same computer that your code(script) is running on. That is to make things a bit more simple. You may have to set permissions using dcomcnfg.

In an attempt to answer some of your questions:

1) To get a list of COM objects and to set permissions, run dcomcnfg. Once the "Component Services" window opens, click on Console Root -> Component Services -> Computers -> My Computers -> DCOM Config. For more information refer to this URL: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb633148.aspx